# Xcode Commoncrypto generate key pair( Private key and public key)

Tags: swift, xcode, encryption, cryptography, decrement

If I use `CommonCryptor` generate key pairs and use `CCECCryptorComputeSharedSecret` to use sharekey form partner public key and my private key, but if someone got my public key and use `CCECCryptorComputeSharedSecret` with their own generate keys they can hack me right? Because in `functionaliststion` generate key pair there's no initial specicfic value for both client and server, do I understand correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You distribute the public key freely, but you keep the private key secret.

> If someone got my public key and use CCECCryptorComputeSharedSecret
>   with their own generate keys they can hack me right?

No. it's not possible by public key

[Create an extra layer of security for your private keys.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services/keys/storing_keys_in_the_secure_enclave)

> Because in functionaliststion generate key pair there's no initial
>   specicfic value for both client and server, do I understand correctly?

If the function fails to create a key, as indicated by a NULL return value, it fills in the error parameter to indicate the reason for failure.

***From apple:*** 
*Asymmetric key cryptography is useful because it enables secure communication between two players who don’t share a secret ahead of time. However, it’s not ideal for bulk data transfer, because it’s computationally expensive and because it operates on small, fixed-sized chunks of data.*

Comment: so if hacker got my private key and a server public key that sent to me then they use CCECCryptorComputeSharedSecret from the both key to get the same share key of both client and server and hacker can decrypt my message, right?